# Add an image to a javascript object

Tags: javascript, image, object, constructor

I am trying to create/invent a new javascript slider object which will work by displaying a base line image:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMUk6.png

then I want to use these 'knobs' to layer on top depending on certain circumstances

https://i.stack.imgur.com/er7CE.png
These have already been 'cut up' and will be placed on one of the three black knobs. I have many different colors because I plan to run through them so that the color appears to transform from one, to the other.

So I need to be able to attach an image to the id I received from the user and then manipulate the image later.

My code:

```
<div id='option1'></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

var slide1 = new slider("option1");
```

My constructor will look something like this:

```
function slider(id) {

var obj = document.getElementById(id);
if (!obj) { 
var state = -1;
return -1;
}
var state = 0; //blank state

//alert("in");
//alert(document.getElementById(id).className);

//this.addClass("hSliderBack"); INCORRECT SYNTAX!!!
$("#"+id).addClass("hSliderBack"); //this works
}
```

I fixed the problem with the addClass above, though a little ugly.

My CSS script:

```
.hSliderBack
{
background-image: url('/Switches/switchLine.png');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
padding-left: 2px;  /* width of the image plus a little extra padding */
display: block;  /* may not need this, but I've found I do */
}
```

This is how I can add a picture to my constructor. Still a lot of work to do, but at least it's a start. Any comments are still appreciated as I am very green!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you write here:

```
//obj.innerHTML = "<img src=' this doesn't seem right to me.
```

is in fact one perfectly reasonable and viable way.   You enter into the DOM the `<img>` node referencing the image you want to display.

However, more common and perhaps more maintainable solution in many cases is to have a CSS style that references a background image, and you enter a `<div>` into the DOM using the style that causes your image to be displayed.

You should ask yourself, though, is it best to do this without any support from tools.   Many of the most popular JavaScript libraries have tools like this built in, or at the very least, have methods that make building this type of code much, much easier.

Of course, if you are doing this to learn the basics of web development before using a framework so you understand what they are doing more thoroughly, more power to you :-)

Comment: To be honest, I've looked for a widget already to meet my needs. However, I decided to build one for myself because, being a perfectionist, I want to make it so it fits my needs exactly. The style is very important to me. I want to make a very good looking webpage, and I won't settle for less (it will be my business webpage). Also, it is interesting to learn how these things are implemented; I can't complain if it makes me a better web-page programmer :).

Comment: As for the code I had written before, I really would like to avoid doing it this way because I need each image to have its own unique id inside the object. I also figured that there was an easier way to do it... well I hope so.

Comment: You can assign a unique id to the image's host tag with either method--in fact, you should.  Also, since you are generating them directly in JavaScript, you can maintain an object pointing to the DOM node, so that you don't even have to look it up by ID.  Don't underestimate the difficulty of building good widgets.   Depending on the needs and scope of your business, accessibility or internationalization can be incredibly difficult to implement well.  The Dojo framework I use (as a Notes/Domino developer) is not the most popular, but it does these things well, for example.

Comment: Just a small business to start, though my customers would be international. Ok, I decided I would try doing it through CSS as you suggested. My problem is now that the code is not working... I've posted up above my constructor and css...